# Symfony2: Access denied after schema name change

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I've rewritten an application in Symfony as a learning exercise, with its MySQL schema virtually identical to the original schema but for a name change.  I did this so I could continue to work with the original application while fiddling with Symfony.

To see whether the rewrite could ever go live I built a script to make minor modifications to the production schema.  Then I changed the name of the database in parameters.yml from the symfony test schema to the live schema name. I can get to the login screen, but any pages beyond that (where all pages are behind a firewall) I get

> request.ERROR:
>   Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\AccessDeniedHttpException:
>   Access Denied (uncaught exception) at
>   G:\Documents\workspace\sym\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\ExceptionListener.php
>   line 100

Symfony profiler shows I'm fully authenticated.

Where to look?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error 99: replace user and try again!

My bad - failed to adequately update the usertable.  Role was not present.  It is now and all is well.

Thanks for listening.

g